# I define three arrays in my index.js file, but my index.ejs file can only identify the first one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to make a to-do list with the 1-3-5 rule, so I create three html forms and want to store them in three different arrays. But my it seems like the .ejs file can only access the task array, but cannot identify task3 and task5.

When I run the code, the browser return: task3 is not defined.
I can't figure out why, please help! Thanks!

index.js (controller)

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
//render css files
app.use(express.static("public"));

//placeholders for added task
var task = [];
var task3 = [];
var task5 = [];
//placeholders for removed task
var complete = [];

//post route for adding new task
app.post("/addtask", function(req, res) {
    var newTask = req.body.newtask;
    task.push(newTask);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/addtask3", function(req, res) {
    var newTask = req.body.newtask3;
    task3.push(newTask);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/addtask5", function(req, res) {
    var newTask = req.body.newtask5;
    task5.push(newTask);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/completetask", function(req, res) {
    var completeTask = req.body.check;
    //check for the "typeof" the different completed task, then add into the complete task
    if (typeof completeTask === "string") {
        complete.push(completeTask);
        //check if the completed task already exits in the task when checked, then remove it
        task.splice(task.indexOf(completeTask), 1);
    } else if (typeof completeTask === "object") {
        for (var i = 0; i < completeTask.length; i++) {
            complete.push(completeTask[i]);
            task.splice(task.indexOf(completeTask[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/removetask", function(req, res) {
    var removeTask = req.body.check;
    //check for the "typeof" the different completed task, then add into the complete task
    if (typeof removeTask === "string") {
        task.splice(task.indexOf(removeTask), 1);
    } else if (typeof removeTask === "object") {
        for (var i = 0; i < removeTask.length; i++) {
            task.splice(task.indexOf(removeTask[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});

//render the ejs and display added task, completed task
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { task: task, complete: complete });
});

//set app to listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

index.ejs (viewer)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> ToDo App </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<h1> ToDo List </h1>
<h2> 1 Big Thing </h2>
<form method="POST">
<p />
<input type="text" name="newtask" placeholder="add big task">
<button formaction="/addtask"> Add </button>
<button formaction="/completetask" type="submit" id="top"> Complete </button>
<button formaction="/removetask" type="submit" id="top"> Delete </button>
<% for( var i = 0; i < task.length; i++){ %>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%= task[i] %>" /> <%= task[i] %> </li>
<% } %>

<h2> 3 Medium Things </h2>
<p />
<input type="text" name="newtask3" placeholder="add medium task">
<button formaction="/addtask3"> Add </button>
<button formaction="/completetask" type="submit" id="top"> Complete </button>
<button formaction="/removetask" type="submit" id="top"> Delete </button>
<% for( var i = 0; i < task3.length; i++){ %>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%= task3[i] %>" /> <%= task3[i] %> </li>
<% } %>

<h2> 5 Small Things </h2>
<p />
<input type="text" name="newtask5" placeholder="add small task">
<button formaction="/addtask5"> Add </button>
<button formaction="/completetask" type="submit" id="top"> Complete </button>
<button formaction="/removetask" type="submit" id="top"> Delete </button>
</form>
<% for( var i = 0; i < task5.length; i++){ %>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%= task5[i] %>" /> <%= task5[i] %> </li>
<% } %>

<h2> Completed task </h2>

 <% for(var i = 0; i < complete.length; i++){ %>
    <li><input type="checkbox" checked><%= complete[i] %> </li>
<% } %>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show the code of the controller passing tasks to the view?

Comment: @lagowp I already edit to show the code, please take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with what you are sending to your view

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { task: task, complete: complete });
});
```

You see? you are rendering the view index, passing two objects to it, `task` and `complete`. Then, on your view, you try to access `task3`, but you've never sent it. For your code to run, you should change this line to

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { task: task, task3: task3, task5: task5, complete: complete });
});
```

Or this, if you are using a modern version of node

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { task, task3, task5, complete });
});
```

Comment: Yea I just figured it out just now >.<, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are rendering the page you are only sending task from server you are not sending task3 and task5 you need to send them too.

before it was

```
//render the ejs and display added task, completed task
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { task: task, complete: complete });
});
```

it should be something like below

```
//render the ejs and display added task, completed task
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { task: task,task3:task3, task5:task5, complete: complete });
```

});

Comment: Yea I just figured it out just now >.<, but thank you anyway!